# Dependency error in React Native for Android

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

I am writing a React Native App for Android. I initialized the project with the react-native-cli. When I try to run it on Android, I get the following error:

```
$ react-native run-android

Scanning folders for symlinks in /path/to/myreactnativeproject/node_modules (6ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'myreactnativeproject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
Required by:
     :myreactnativeproject:unspecified

* Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.226 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed Android Studio 3.0.1. What is the reason for the error?

**Edit:** When I run it with stacktrace, info and debug, I get the following output:

I can't post the output here, because it is to long: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/QvPi2p7r)

Comment: > Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: What happens when you do what the message tells you to do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a link to the output with info, debug and stacktrace @Code-Apprentice

Comment: > 23:55:41.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.

Comment: I updated the version in _build.gradle_ to 2.2.3. But now I get the following error: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/c3P39CEp). It seems like it can't validate the SSL encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this to *.bashrc*:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```